# how do you clear jobs from ActiveJob queue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I have a job that performs a state change, and the way I'm using it, the state is changed only after a certain amount of time has passed.

In my job class:

```
class ItemJob < ApplicationJob
 queue_as :default

 def perform(item)
  item.do_this!
 end
end
```

And it's being called from a model:

```
def create_item_worker
 ItemJob.set(wait: 30.seconds).perform_later(self)
end
```

However this is not working because ActiveJob has a queue of jobs for records that no longer exist. I type `bundle exec sidekiq` into Terminal and it spits out crap like `ActiveJob::DeserializationError: Error while trying to deserialize arguments: Couldn't find Item with 'id'=67`.

So how do I clear that? `Sidekiq::Queue.all.each(&:clear)` doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your job is not enqueued anymore since it failed, it is waiting in the retry set to be re-enqueued at a later time.  You want `Sidekiq::RetrySet.new.clear`.

Please read the API and Error Handling wiki pages to learn more.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API